# wait() and notify() related issue

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I simply want to use thread to print out from 1 to 10. But my code will stop at number 1. input() will provide variable from 1 to 10, while output() will print out them. input() will be executed first and then output(). After that for() will make sure they will start another iteration.

```
class InputOutput{
    private static int i=0;
    private static boolean ToF=false;

    synchronized void output(){
        try{
            while(!ToF){
                notify();
                wait();
            }
        }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("Output: "+i);
        ToF=false;
        notify();
    }
    synchronized void input(){
        try{
            while(ToF){
                notify();
                wait();
            }
        }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        i++;
        ToF=true;
        notify();
    }
    class input implements Runnable{
    private int i=1;
    InputOutput io=new InputOutput();
    public void run(){
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
            io.input();
    }
    }
    class output implements Runnable{
    private int i=1;
    InputOutput io=new InputOutput();
    public void run(){
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
            io.output();
    }
    }
    public class Homework07Part3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1=new Thread(new input());
        t1.start();
        Thread t2=new Thread(new output());
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about java naming conventions. Class names start UpperCase. And avoid giving the same names to classes and methods. Method names are about verbs; like fetchInput() or pushOutput() or something alike. And: you expect us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly indent/format your code!

Comment: You are creating 2 `InputOutput` objects. One for each thread which means that the `input` and `output` methods that you're calling don't synchronise on the same object. Even if they were to synchronise on the same object, the logic is wrong, you don't need loops to achieve what you want.

Comment: I am so sorry I forget naming rule. You are correct I should keep that rule.

Comment: Beyond that: what makes you think that **input** will start first? Just because you call t1.start() an then t2.start() doesn't (necessarily mean) that t1 really starts before t2.

Comment: Cause ToF is set to false at first and then output will wait until input notify it right?

Comment: Titus, thank you for your comment. It helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while loop you put wait on a single object for which two thread communication

```
while(ToF){
           //dont put notify here.
            notify();
            wait();
        }
```

Make it instance variable

```
private static boolean ToF=false;
```

public class Homework07Part3 {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputOutput io = new InputOutput();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new input(io));
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new output(io));
        t2.start();
    }

    private static class input implements Runnable {
        private int i = 1;
        private InputOutput io;

        public input(InputOutput io) {
            this.io = io;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                io.input();
        }
    }

    private static class output implements Runnable {
        private int i = 1;
        private InputOutput io;

        public output(InputOutput io) {
            this.io = io;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                io.output();
        }
    }
}

class InputOutput {
    private int i = 0;
    private boolean ToF = false;

    synchronized void output() {
        try {
            while (!ToF) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Output: " + i);
        ToF = false;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized void input() {
        try {
            while (ToF) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i++;
        ToF = true;
        notify();
    }

}
```

Comment: I voted but due to my low reputation, it is not displayed. Thank you so much, dude.

Answer (score 0):

> I simply want to use thread to print out from 1 to 10. But my code will stop at number 1.

[[ The other answer seems to have fixed your problem but it doesn't explain *what* is happening and why the fix works. ]]

You problem is that both threads are calling `synchronize` and `notify()` and `wait()` on *different* objects.  When threads communicate using these signals they both need to be sharing the same object instance.  You are creating 2 `InputOutput` objects so both of your threads are stuck in `wait()` since the `notify()` calls are lost.

```
class Input implements Runnable{
    ...
    // this is local to the Input class
    InputOutput io=new InputOutput();
...
class Output implements Runnable{
    ...
    // this is a different instance 
    InputOutput io=new InputOutput();
```

You should do something like the following:

```
final InputOutput io = new InputOutput();
Thread t1=new Thread(new Input(io));
t1.start();
Thread t2=new Thread(new Output());
t2.start();
...
private static class Input {
    private final InputOutput io;
    public Input(InputOutput io) { this.io = io; }
...
private static class Output {
    private final InputOutput io;
    public Output(InputOutput io) { this.io = io; }
...
```

So then both of your `Input` and `Output` classes are using the same instance of the `InputOutput` class.  When they call `synchronized` on the methods, they are locking on the same instance and when they call `wait()` and `notify()` the signals are seen by the other thread.